# Simplifying how I connect to a OpenVPN client

Tags: arch-linux, openvpn

Following the Arch Wiki's [guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ProtonVPN) to ProtonVPN, I have **several** `.ovpn` files inside `/etc/openvpn/client`. Every time I want to connect to a certain server, I need to fully type the command:

`sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/client/file.ovpn`

Given that my shell autocompletion does not work for file name for some reason, what would be the recommended way to simplify how I connect to a server? I'm sure there must be some application that manages what's inside the `client` folder for the user so a simple command suffices, but for some reason I couldn't find one.

I could always use an alias in my shell configuration for the most common servers I connect to, but it seems counterintuitive to work in this way.

**Obs:** I could use the `protonvpn` package itself instead, but I can't seem to make it work out of the box on my machine, so I'm disregarding it here.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of possibilities that I can think of:

**The shell method**

Other than using aliases, a quick and dirty way is to make a shell script that does the boring stuff for you:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/client/$1.ovpn
```

You probably don't have billions of configuration scripts, so this should work fine.

**The NetworkManager method**

If you're using NetworkManager, you can install the `networkmanager-openvpn` package and use `nmcli` to import the connection's `.ovpn` file, as described in the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/OpenVPN#NetworkManager-native_VPN_configuration):

```
nmcli connection import type openvpn file <file.ovpn>
```

There is a nice graphical interface in Gnome and KDE for the NetworkManager OpenVPN client too, if that's important. :-)